# Why i can't create object from custom class in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

the object will not show in the hierarchy, and in other script which derived from MonoBehaviour call GameObject.Find("/Canvas") is null.

```
public class SceneUI
{
    [RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod]
    private static void __OnSceneChange()
    {
        Debug.Log("The Scene Had Changed To：" + SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
        __Init();
    }

    private static GameObject canvas;
    private static void __Init()
    {
        canvas = GameObject.Find("/Canvas") ?? new GameObject("Canvas");
        bool cmd;
        cmd = canvas.GetComponent<Canvas>() ?? canvas.AddComponent<Canvas>();
        cmd = canvas.GetComponent<CanvasScaler>() ?? canvas.AddComponent<CanvasScaler>();
        cmd = canvas.GetComponent<GraphicRaycaster>() ?? canvas.AddComponent<GraphicRaycaster>();

        foreach (dynamic pairs in GameApp.DataConf_["NavicatResource"])
        {
            GameObject dog = new GameObject("Puppy");
            string scene_name = pairs.Value.sceneName;
            DefaultControls.Resources ui_res = new DefaultControls.Resources();
            GameObject uiButton = DefaultControls.CreateButton(ui_res);
            uiButton.transform.SetParent(canvas.transform, false);
            uiButton.transform.position = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you should include a copy (screen shop, error msg, etc.) of the error you are getting when execute.

Comment: Whatever else may be wrong, you are trying to assign MonoBehaviors to a bool (```bool cmd = canvas.GetComponent<Canvas>()```)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because i changed the scene。 I should add

```
DontDestroyOnLoad(canvas)；
```

after

```
canvas = GameObject.Find("/Canvas") ?? new GameObject("Canvas");
```